# My Python for loop is causing a MemoryError. How can I optimize this?

Tags: python, optimization, memory, out-of-memory

I'm trying to compile a list of all the MAC address Apple devices will have. `oui.txt` tells me Apple has been assigned 77 MAC ranges to use. These ranges come in the form of:

```
00:00:00
00:11:11
etc...
```

This leaves me the last three HEX digits to append. That's `16^6`. A total of 1291845632 Apple MAC addresses.

The problem I'm having is writing a program to create a list of these MAC addresses. Here's my current code:

```
import re

apple_mac_range = []
apple_macs      = []

# Parse the HTML of http://standards.ieee.org/cgi-bin/ouisearch to get the MACs
with open('apple mac list', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():

        match = re.search(r'[\w\d]{2}-[\w\d]{2}-[\w\d]{2}', line)

        if match:
            apple_mac_range.append(match.group().split('-'))

for mac in apple_mac_range:
    for i in range(1, 1291845633):
        print i
```

This gives me a `MemoryError`... How can I optimize it?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to generate a complete list of all those MAC addresses?

Comment: Why do you need to enumerate over one billion addresses?  What is the problem you are really trying to solve?

Comment: Well, I really only want iPhone device MACs but, from what I've found so far, Apple doesn't seem to have a specific range(s) they use for certain devices.

Comment: That's not answering the question. **Why do you need these MACs**? Why do you need to enumerate them ahead of time? What are you going to **do with them**?

Answer (score 18):

`range(1, 1291845633)` creates a list of 1,291,845,632 elements (several GB) all at once. Use `xrange(1, 1291845633)` instead and it will generate elements as you need them instead of all at once.

Regardless, it looks like you want something more like this:

```
for mac in apple_mac_range: 
    for i in xrange(16777216): 
        print mac, i
```

Of course it's quite likely that a list of 1.3e+9 MAC addresses will not be very useful. If you want to see if a given MAC address is an Apple device, you should just check to see if the 3-byte prefix is in the list of 77. If you're trying to do access control by giving a router or something a list of all possible MAC addresses, it's unlikely that the device will accept 1.3e+9 items in its list.

Answer (score 3):

Others have answered your *actual* question, but I'm not really sure that's what's warranted here.  Why don't you just create a class which implements `__contains__` to test MAC address algorithmically?  I presume you're getting a MAC and you want to test if it's possibly an iPhone MAC, so you could implement that class and then just do something like:

```
if found_mac in MACTester:
  ...do work...
```

Alternatively if you really do want an iterable sequence, you should at least use a generator instead of actually trying to fit them all in memory.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
i = 0
while i < 1291845633:
  print i
  i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use readlines

```
with file('apple mac list') as f:
    for x in f:
        print x
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start with, `range(1, 1291845633)` creates a list containing about a billion entries.  Since each entry is at least `sizeof(Py_Object)`, it's not too surprising that you run right out of memory.  Don't do that.